# Fluent nHibernate Id is a reference

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a situation where two tables share the same key, let's just say ID. When I'm mapping those two tables with FluentMapping, how I do the mapping for the class where I want the ID actually to map to an object.

```
public class First
{
    public virtual int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual string Name {get; set; }
}


public class Second
{
    public virtual First First {get; set;}
    public virtual int Number {get; set; }
}
```

How do I map the Second class? Second table has also a ID, but it's a foreign key to the First table's id.

Comment: in that case, would you say that `Second` *is a kind of* `First`? meaning- like an `Employee` is a kind of `Person`, or a `Manager` is a kind of `Employee`. If so- you'll want to use inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

like sJhonny said this really sounds like inheritance which would give

```
class First
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

class Second : First
{
    public virtual int Number { get; set; }
}

class FirstMap : ClassMap<First>
{
    public FirstMap()
    {
        Id(f => f.Id).GeneratedBy.HiLo("100");

        Map(f => f.Name);
    }
}

class SecondMap : SubclassMap<Second>
{
    public SecondMap()
    {
        KeyColumn("Id");

        Map(s => s.Number);
    }
}
```

but your scenario is also possible, but you need additional work and its not so nice in code later

```
class SecondMap : ClassMap<Second>
{
    public SecondMap()
    {
        CompositeId()
            .KeyReference(f => f.First, "Id");

        Map(s => s.Number);
    }
}

class Second
{
    public virtual First First {get; set;}
    public virtual int Number { get; set; }

    // required for Compositekeys
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as Second;
        return (other != null) && (First.Id == other.First.Id) ;
    }

    // required for Compositekeys
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return First.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```